# Why is this erroring out with "unable to infer enough type information about `_`"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have some supposedly easy code in Rust:

```
 let d = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8];
 for x in d.iter()
            .take(5) 
            .product() {                                                                            
                println!("{} is the product !", x)                                                                                                                                             
            }
```

When I run this code however I get the error:

```
src/functional.rs:63:9: 67:14 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
src/functional.rs:63         for x in d.iter()
src/functional.rs:64             .take(5)
src/functional.rs:65             .product() {
src/functional.rs:66                 println!("{} is the product !", x)
src/functional.rs:67             }
src/functional.rs:63:9: 67:14 help: run `rustc --explain E0282` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `gettingrusty`.
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Sorry missed out on that. I have added

Answer (score 3):

The [`product`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product) method (unstable as of Rust 1.5) produces a single value from an iterator; it doesn't yield another iterator. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to use it in a `for` loop.

However, even with the following code, we still get the same error:

```
#![feature(iter_arith)]

fn main() {
    let d = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8];
    let v = d.iter().take(5).product();
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

The error comes from the compiler being unable to figure out the result type of `product`. I'm not sure why; it might be a bug in the compiler, or it might just be the case that it's ambiguous. Adding a type suffix on one of the literals in the array (e.g. changing `2` to `2i32`) doesn't fix this, and specifying the type of `d` (to e.g. `[i32; 5]`) doesn't help either. That means we need to tell the compiler what type we expect to get from `product`.

```
let v: i32 = d.iter().take(5).product();
// or
let v = d.iter().take(5).product::<i32>();
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Francis' answer, the use of the `feature` attribute will require a nightly build of Rust (that is, the stable version you probably downloaded won't let you run his solution).

On the other hand... you can roll your own and do something like this:

```
let d = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8];
let x = d.iter()
        .take(5)
        .fold(1, |a, b| a * b);

println!("{} is the product !", x);
```

Which [will run happily on the stable release](http://is.gd/INoECn)